# What is the proper way to use the buffer's content on the cpu side in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, buffer, mirror

Let's imagine that I have two squeres. Firstly I generate the VAO, VBO, then bind it and so on... My goal is to check the collision between the two objects in every frame. In this case, I have to know the exact verticies both the cpu and the gpu side. So I store every single vertex twice. If I work with large amount of data, the mirroring not seems to be efficient, not to mention the logistic about keeping the data consistent. Is there a better way to do this? Or this is totally OK, to keep the verticies in an array after the glBufferData call?

Comment: If you want to perform collision detection between objects, then look into bounding volumes and simplified collision hulls. There's various ways to perform a more accurate comparison, but it's extremely rarely that you'd need a "*1 to 1*" comparison. *I of course don't know the context of your project.*

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be more information on your part. Is this something you plan on instancing? Are you sure there's a bottleneck on your bandwidth?

If this is something that you can simulate on the GPU, then just do it all on the GPU so you keep the memory on that side and not incur the transfer penalty from CPU to GPU.

If you need it to be on the CPU side for your collision detection, then you have a few options:

- Update the ones that change. If all of them are changing you should ignore this option, but you could map the buffer and update it and try to flush it only after you've updated what ranges are needed.
- Send a displacement. If you end up having a ton of data, you may be able to get away with just sending a rotation and central position to cut down on updating "every vertex", and might be able to exploit a Geometry Shader... however I've read that these can be problematic for performance so you should consider it but be ready to profile.
- You can possibly stream data if you have to update all of them, see [this wonderful resource](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf).

You need to define your problem domain a bit more because I'm not sure exactly what the bounds on the problem are. The above are *some* ways of tackling these problems, but the best solution can only be given to you if you are more specific with what you want when you talk about the large case.

You also have to understand that asking for massive data manipulation and fast transfer tend to be topics that fight each other, and you'll have to be smarter about what you plan on doing depending on exactly how much data you are talking about here.

I'd like to answer with something more concrete but I'm just shooting in the dark because I don't know exactly what the limit of your data is and what hardware you're working with.

Comment: I don't have any exact code, because I'm asking theoretically. I want to build a 2D game, and I'm planning to make a class which contains the vao and the verticies of the object. My idea is to modify the verticies, and update the buffer every time when an object moves. In this case I'm updating the buffer continuously. If I'm not wrong, moving the data between the CPU and the GPU is slow, that's why I should avoid from it.

Comment: @randomguy I still need more information. For example, what is your framerate? Is it bound by vsync or some constant, or unbounded? Why would you send all of the squares over? You should only be sending what is visible on the screen. The amount of objects on the screen are likely so small that you can probably transfer them all without really noticing. Another issue here is that it's premature optimization, especially if you haven't thought of culling yet. Transfer of data isn't _that_ slow, you can fire off a nice amount of data each frame and be okay (I've done this myself).